# How to close autocomplete dropdown on side click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete

I user `jquery autocomplete` to fetch some results and results are displayed but when I click on the side can't close dropdown with returned results.

```
$(function () {
            $("#search").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("TestAutoComplete", "Home")', type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                        data: { query: request.term },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {

                                return {
                                    label: item.Title
                                };
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 1,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    onItemSelect(ui.item);
                },
                open: function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('ui-corner-all').addClass('ui-corner-top');
                    $(this).autocomplete('widget').css('z-index', 999999);
                },
                close: function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('ui-corner-top').addClass('ui-corner-all');
                }
            })
        .data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $('<li>')
                .data('autocomplete-item', item)
                .append('<a href="#"><p  >' + item.label + "</p></a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
        };
        });
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsfiddle for us to play with?

Comment: The autocomplete has this functionality by default. What version of jquery and jquery ui are you using? If you can re-produce the problem in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) then it would be alot easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very stupid error.

```
 $("#search").autocomplete({...
```

it should be

```
 $(".search").autocomplete({...
```

and it work.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup isn't totally clear to me from just looking at your js but it would be something like this:

```
$("html").on("click.autocomplete", function(e){
  var $targ = $(e.target || event.srcElement);
  if ( !$targ.is( /* searchlist */ ) || !$( /* searchlist */ ).has( $targ ).length ) {
    //Close autocomplete
    $("html").off(".autocomplete");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You leave us somehow blinded of your implementation, but assuming a good pattern the solution would be, detect on every click on the document if the element that was clicked (e.target) ) is inside the search else close the searchbox.

```
$(document).on('click', function(e)
{
    var jqTarget = $(e.target);
    if ( !jqTarget.closest('#search').length ) 
    {
        $("#search").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var that = $('.autocomplete'); //Define this somewhere in the page to refer later

$('document').on('mousedown', function(e){
if ($(e.target).closest('.autocomplete:not(:visible)').length != 0) {
        that.hide();
    }
});
```